# Is a hatched jqueryui slider range/background possible?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, colors, slider

Is it possible to have the range/background of a jqueryui slider hatched or even filled with a colour gradient (see http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Unintuitive-rgb.png)

It's not just about changing the colour, but rather make it ranging from red->green depending on certain variables -- which of course may vary at runtime...

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You just need to set the  background of your  slider div.

```
<div id="slider" style="background:black"></div>
```

This will cause the slider to have a black background.

That is the easy part. The question is how will you create a gradient?

For a CSS implementation look at http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient/
You might want to look into the cssHooks option in jQuery to streamline it. See also https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks for some examples (there is a gradient.js cssHook, but it as far as I checked it didn't support IE).

For the best result, you might want to set a background image instead, for example:

```
<div id="slider" style="background:url(creategradient.aspx?from=000&to=FFF&height=5&width=100)"></div>
```

You'll have to write some server side code that will create the gradient picture on the fly.

Comment: I can't use a static background image, but -moz-linear-gradient(top,  red, yellow, green) works fine for firefox 3.6+

Comment: However, I end up with a brownish color in the middle using progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ff0000", endColorstr="#00ff00") for IE... does anyone know how to define red->yellow->green in here?

Comment: Its (multiple stops) not supported in IE. That's why the background pic would be the best option.

Comment: My point is that thresholds for red/green might change often so that the (static) background image must be regenerated each time. Nevermind, I stick to firefox for the moment. Thanks for your immediate feedback!

Comment: Well if browser support isn't an issue, than sure go for that. Otherwise I don't see the problem of creating images on the fly.